# Unable to add prefix to ActiveRecord enum in Rails 4.2.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

According to [Active Record#Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) docs, I am able to prefix an enum to avoid conflict like so:

```
enum comments_status: [:active, :inactive], _prefix: :comments
```

My implementation is:

```
enum appointed_position: {
    master:              0,
    concierge:           1
  }, _prefix: :appointed
```

However, when I run my tests, it gives me this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each_with_index' for :appointed:Symbol
```

How to make this work?

Apparently, in ActiveRecord 4.2.6, they removed "_prefix" and "_suffix" options from the `enum.rb`. So is there an alternative?

Comment: They didn't remove it, it just isn't out yet. Those docs are for Rails 5 (see the issue here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19813)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not released yet. Check 4.2.6 API doc
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Or use latest Rails, which is currently Rails 5, beta 3